# Как вызвать обобщенный метод через рефлекию

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

У меня есть несколько классов:

```
internal static class Ensure
{
    public static Parameter<T> That<T>(T value)
    {
        return new Parameter<T>(value);
    }
}

internal sealed class Parameter<T>
{
    private readonly T value;

    public Parameter(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public T Value => value;
}

internal static class ParameterExtensions
{
    public static void IsNotNull<T>(this Parameter<T> @this)
        where T : class
    {
        if(@this.Value==null)
        {
            throw new Exception("cannot be null.");
        }
    }

    public static void IsInRange<T>(this Parameter<T> @this, T minimum, T maximum)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (@this.Value.CompareTo(minimum) < 0 ||
            @this.Value.CompareTo(maximum) > 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов метода с использованием такого класса выглядит так:

```
 string name="MynName"
 Ensure.That(name).IsNotNull();
```

Мне нужно этот же метод вызвать через рефлексию (если метод принимает параметры или нет):

```
 void MethodCall(string methodName)
 {
     Type parameterExtensions = typeof(ParameterExtensions);
     MethodInfo method = parameterExtensions.GetMethod(methodName);
     method = method.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);

     method.Invoke(null, new object[] {Ensure.That(property.GetValue(this))); 
     //тут вылетает исключение : Parameter`1[System.Object]' cannot be converted to type 'Parameter`1[System.String]'.'
  }
```

Comment: Если обратиться к msdn, то первый параметр для invoke это экземпляр от имени которого будет вызван метод. А также `If a method is static, this argument is ignored.`.

Comment: Вот в качестве аргументов вызова invoka вы уже отдаете стрингу. Ensure.That()  должен оказаться как параметр.

Comment: откуда берется `property`, и какой в итоге `property.PropertyType`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот код, который делает то, что вы хотите

```
   class Caller
   {
        private string SomeProperty { get; set; }= "value1";

        public void MethodCall()
        {
            Type parameterExtensions = typeof(Ensure);
            MethodInfo method = parameterExtensions.GetMethod("That");

            var property = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == "SomeProperty");
            method = method.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);
            var result = method.Invoke(null, new object[] { property.GetValue(this) });

            Type parameter = typeof(ParameterExtensions);
            MethodInfo methodIsNotNull = parameter.GetMethod("IsNotNull");
            methodIsNotNull = methodIsNotNull.MakeGenericMethod(property.PropertyType);

            methodIsNotNull.Invoke(null, new object[] { result });
       }
   }
```

**Пояснение:**

Чтобы вызывать целевой метод расширения `IsNotNull`, вам сначала необходимо вызывать метод `That`, который создает вам объект класса `Parameter<T>`, а далее уже через данный экземпляр вызвать и метод расширения.

Поэтому данный метод рефлексии сначала вызывает метод `That`, который возвращает экземпляр класса `Parameter<T>`, а далее вызывает метод расширение `IsNotNull`, передавая в качестве аргумента только что созданный экземпляр.